# unix goto command source code

Tags: c, shell, unix

Here is the source code of a historical Unix goto.c: http://v6shell.org/history/goto.c

So we're trying to find a matching label recording the "goto label" call.

My problem:

```
if (getlin(line)) {
        write(1, "label not found\n", 16);
        return;
        }
```

So I would expect if getlin() returns true we should print out "label not found" and exit the program.

But look at this:

```
getlin(s)
char s[];
{
    int ch, i;

    i = 0;
l:
    if ((ch=getc())=='\0') return(1);
    if (ch!=':') {
        while(ch!='\n' && ch!='\0')
            ch = getc();
        goto l;
        }
    while ((ch=getc())==' ');
    while (ch!=' ' && ch!='\n' && ch!='\0') {
        s[i++] = ch;
        ch = getc();
        }
    while(ch != '\n')
        ch = getc();
    s[i] = '\0';
    return(0);
}
```

getlin() will return 0(true) if we found the label and 1(false) if we didn't.

But it should be the other way around or we would need to say:

```
if (**!** getlin(line)){}
```

**What is wrong here?**

Comment: Not sure what this is about, but as a general rule of thumb: unix utilities traditionally return 0 (zero) to indicate success, everything else indicates an error (an error code). So I#d say the function implementation makes sense, the conditional is questionable.

Comment: Yeah that's the question. 
But it's working, so why does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0` is treated as `false` in `C`. Hence the confusion. You can try out by running this small sample of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;

int main() {
  if(i) {
    printf("i is %d and it is true\n", i);
  } else {
    printf("i is %d and it is false\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

As an exit code, `0` is considered SUCCESS. But in conditionals (in `C`), `0` evaluates to `false` and `1` evaluates to `true`.

But, in bash, `0` is considered `true`, even in conditionals. That is because it was more convenient that way in most use cases for bash, since we are always dealing with processes.